# Get value when pressing a button

Tags: php, html, button

How to post a value from div when click on button.

I have tried to leave the action blank so it will refresh the site when pressing the button. But the value does not come to? I only want TransID to post when pressing the button.

```
<form action=" ">
        <div class="white-box">

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3">TransID</div>
                    <div class="span3">Medlemsnummer</div>
                    <div class="span4">Beskrivelse</div>
                    <div class="span2">Indløs</div>

                </div>
                <?php
                foreach($Test as $key){
                ?>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3" id="TransNR" >#<?= $key['TransID']; ?></div>
            <div class="span3"><?= $key['member_id']; ?></div>
            <div class="span4"><?= $key['title']; ?></div>

            <?php 
            $indløst = isset($key['indløst'])?($key['indløst']) :"";
            ?>
            <?php 
            if($indløst)
            { 
            ?>
            <div class="span2" ><?= date('d-m-y H:i:s', $indløst) ?></div>
            <?php 
            } 
            else 
            {
            ?>
            <input class="span2" type="submit" value="Ja ">
            <?php }
            ?>         

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div><!-- / white-box -->

    </form>
```

Comment: This is not the right way.Just use ajax

Comment: use header tag to refresh the page after processing request.

Comment: you at least need a request method, either POST or GET, also normal request methods are catching the name attributes

Comment: Zaz, instead please tell us what you *want* to accomplish? Do you want to submit data using POST to another PHP script? Or do you want to avoid refreshing page and just have the form be processed on client side (with JavaScript)?

Comment: I want to submit data using POST to another PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden input to store the variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TransID" value="<?= $key['TransID']; ?>" />
```

Your form will send it by `GET` method as you are not specifying the `method` to be sent.
If you want to send it by `POST`, change your form to:

```
<form action=" " method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this..

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-mini" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="somefunction('<?=$key['TransID']?>');" id="somefunction" data-original-title="somefunction">Some text </a>
```

Or

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-mini"  href="somefile.php?id=<?=$key['TransID']?>"  >Some text </a>
```

Comment: When i am using the second one, it cant find the row